# Unable to add image validation in nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs and i am using express js for api,Right now i am working on "image upload api", image is uploading into server but i want to add 2 validations

1. validation on image height and width
2. Only "jpg,jpeg,png" image extension should allow
   Right now i am getting "image-dimension" and "image extension" but i dont know that how can i add/use this into my api,Here is my code

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
   //const originalnames = file.originalname;
   callback(null, './uploads');
  },
 
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
 var sizeOf = require('image-size');
 const originalname = file.originalname;
 const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
 const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
 console.log("mimetype is " + file.mimetype);  // GETTING IMAGE EXTENSION HERE
 const dimensions = sizeOf(`./uploads/${excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt}`);  // GETTING IMAGE DIMENSION HERE
   
    callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
      },
});

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any('userPhoto');
  const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
  if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```